# Replace recurring code blocks with slight differences by using a macro

Tags: c++, macros, c++17

In my source file, I have several blocks of code which have long recurring parts. Take this block as an example:

```
void MemberFunctionBar([..], SomeClass param, [..]) {
    /* long common part */

    if constexpr (SafeCopy) {
        T copyOfParam(param);

        /* many lines of code */
        Foo(std::move(copyOfParam));
    } else {
        /* many lines of code (exactly the same as above) */
        Foo(param);
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to have these intermediate lines written only once, for better code maintainability. Furthermore, no further function calls may be made, due to limitations. The code should expand into the original form if possible.

So far, I was thinking of something like this macro (which obviously does not work, as preprocessor directives inside macros are not interpreted):

```
#define IF_SAFE_COPY_COPY_PARAM(block)                \
    if constexpr (SafeCopy) {                         \
        T paramCopy(param);                           \
        #define __the_param__ std::move(paramCopy)    \
        block                                         \
        #undef __the_param__                          \
    } else {                                          \
        #define __the_param__ param                   \
        block                                         \
        #undef __the_param__                          \
    }

void MemberFunctionBar([..], SomeClass param, [..]) {
    /* long common part */
    IF_SAFE_COPY_COPY_PARAM({
        /* many lines of code */
        Foo(__the_param__);
    })
}
```

Even though there are limitations (no additional function calls), I'm still open for suggestions.

Comment: Seems to me that you can put the code in a function and call that...

Comment: @tobi303 yeah baby, synchronous commenting

Comment: Why are you concerned with the safety of a copy if the `param` is by value always? Do you _actually_ need deep cloning behaviour on some types of `SomeClass`? Because then you'd just write a value-wrapper and apply rule of zero.

Comment: btw already the "many lines of code" suggest that your real code isnt very readable and you should do something about it. Once you do this, the duplication of code will also be easier to solve, while using a macro just make things worse

Comment: @tobi303 Well in theory I absoluetly agree. Nevertheless, people tend to write "optimized answers" which then sometimes aren't applicable to the actual problem anymore. By implying a small code mess, nobody tries to optimize those parts, while still answering the crucial part of the question. ;)

Comment: The `if` is `constexpr`, so what does it matter to do the check twice? First for the `T copyOfParam(param);`, then the long common block, then second for the call on `Foo`.

Comment: @AndyG The local `paramCopy` variable would immediatly be destroyed by the end of the scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an higher-order function:

```
template <typename F>
void MemberFunctionBar( SomeClass param, F&& f) {
    if constexpr (SafeCopy) {
        T copyOfParam(param);

        std::forward<F>(f)(/*...*/);
        Foo(std::move(copyOfParam));
    } else {
        std::forward<F>(f)(/*...*/);
        Foo(param);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MemberFunctionBar(my_param, [](/*...*/){ /* block of code */ });
```

Comment: It's done when the `F` is perfectly forwarded :) Also, the X/Y smell is probably "Why is OP writing std::invoke/std::apply manually"

Comment: At first I was sceptical, but the longer I think about this solution, the better it gets. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @ nyronium thinking longer always pays off. In this case, I'd worry about the real reasons you needed this. Like @tobi303 also hints. By framing the question you make it impossible for us to see the real problem, but experience tells me more design (re)thinking will pay off even more.

Comment: @sehe Don't worry. One might suspect that there's a real problem hidden somewhere beneath, but let me reassure you that this is not the case. You folks have done a great job by providing the hint I needed. And this even though I might have been a bit vague about the parameter by-value thing, while I only wanted to point out that there's a parameter.

Comment: why `std::forward<F>(f)();` not just `f()`?

Comment: @MarekR: `f::operator()` could be ref-qualified.

Comment: I have never seen a ref-qualified `operator()` live, is there a useful pattern I have missed?